What special merit did Aharon Hakohen have to bring the Ananei Hakovod?
The Gemara Taanis (9a) writes

מֵיתִיבִי, רַבִּי יוֹסֵי בְּרַבִּי יְהוּדָה אוֹמֵר: שְׁלֹשָׁה
פַּרְנָסִים טוֹבִים עָמְדוּ לְיִשְׂרָאֵל, אֵלּוּ הֵן: מֹשֶׁה וְאַהֲרֹן
וּמִרְיָם. וְשָׁלֹשׁ מַתָּנוֹת טוֹבוֹת נִיתְּנוּ עַל יָדָם, וְאֵלּוּ
הֵן: בְּאֵר, וְעָנָן, וּמָן. בְּאֵר — בִּזְכוּת מִרְיָם, עַמּוּד עָנָן
— בִּזְכוּת אַהֲרֹן, מָן — בִּזְכוּת מֹשֶׁה. מֵתָה מִרְיָם —
נִסְתַּלֵּק הַבְּאֵר, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: ״וַתָּמׇת שָׁם מִרְיָם״, וּכְתִיב
בָּתְרֵיהּ: ״וְלֹא הָיָה מַיִם לָעֵדָה״, וְחָזְרָה בִּזְכוּת
שְׁנֵיהֶן -  The Gemara raises an objection from a baraisa: Rebbi
Yosei, son of Rebbi Yehuda, says: Three good sustainers rose up for
the Jewish people during the exodus from Egypt, and they are: Moshe,
Aharon and Miriam. And three good gifts were given from Heaven through
their agency, and these are they: The well of water, the pillar of
cloud, and the manna. The well was given to the Jewish
people in the merit of Miriam; the pillar of cloud was in the merit of
Aharon; and the manna in the merit of Moshe. When Miriam died the well
disappeared, as it is stated: “And Miriam died there” (Numbers 20:1),
and it says thereafter in the next verse: “And there was no water for
the congregation” (Numbers 20:2). But the well returned in the merit
of both Moshe and Aharon.

What unique merit did Aharon have to deserve the Ananei Hakovod initially?

Did not Aharon go with Moshe to face pharoh and protect Moshe, while all elders initially went but stepped down? There were a few other merits.
